# Page Layout with Spaces

Tags: html, css, layout

I was hoping someone would be able to give me a hand with a page layout I created using CSS & HTML. I am new to CSS and trying to learn it.

You can find the site [here](http://www.glennrosecommunity.com/form_vehicle.asp)

I am having a problem with spacing for the Homeowners & Renters First Name and Last Name to be evenly spaced below like the fields below them. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I have tried everything and nothing seems to work! Strange!! Thanks!

Comment: I must be blind, don't see anything that jumps at me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<p>` elements around the `<input>` elements have default top and bottom margins of `1em` (in Chrome), unlike the `<div>` elements around the other `<input>`s.